# Anyway to get jthread tid through JVMTI?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvmti

There is an function of JVMTI called *GetAllThreads*.
But we can only get jthread object. Is there any way to get the tid for a jthread object?
By tid I mean kernel thread id returned by gettid() system call.

Comment: For what do you need this? I needed it for uniquely identifying the threads, I choose to generate my own id whenever a thread was started. Although this method slows down the profiling a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the thread ID is not provided by the function [Get Thread Info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetThreadInfo) in the JVMTI. If you want to get the thread id as returned by Thread.getId() I assume you have to do this with Bytecode instrumentation.